# Figure out an H-bridge's datasheet

Tags: voltage, current, datasheet, h-bridge

As I am a beginner at electrical engineering, I try to figure out the reccomended operation conditions for H-bridge SN754410 (http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slrs007b/slrs007b.pdf).

I intend to supply with: VCC1: 5 V, VCC2: 9 V. The input signal, I see that has to be 2 - 5.5 V. What about current in case I have a 2 V input signal?

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question be but aware that the TI device is not capable of driving motors with more than 1A and that from a 9V supply, the motor voltage at 1A will have fallen to more like 6V. There are better devices!

Comment: If I understood, this is because in the datasheet, the maximum rating for continuous output current is 1.1 A, right?

Comment: Yes but look at other parts of the spec for Vhigh (and Vlow) under load conditions of 1A - they can lose round about 1.5V from either power Vcc or 0V.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I managed to measure current that motor requires, by connecting multimeter in series. I saw that motor spins at max rpm, with 0.3 A. However, multimeter initially shows 1.7 A to fall into msecs into 0.3 A and keep this value. Is this a problem for using H-bridge SN754410? I mean, is the initial value of current able to damage the device?

Comment: Peak output current (<5ms) is max(absolute) at +/-2A so you may be exceeding this if the 1.7A is for more than 5ms - you are too close for comfort in my book and this current was measured without a load - you really need to rate H bridges at stall current which I suspect will be over 2A and for an indefinite length of time. You really need something with more grunt.

Comment: I would be appeciate, if you had a look at my new post "Figure out an H-bridge's datasheet [part 2]". Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page 4 of your datasheet shows I-IH and I-IL, both maximum 10uA, in other words: in most cases too low to be of any trouble.

[image]